# Xamarin forms IOS App aksing for RootviewController

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin Forms on VS 2017. Whenever I am running My IOS app it is asking for RootViewController but my other sample app is working perfectly without any exception.

My Other app has a default Implementation of Finishedlaunching. AppDelegate is inherited by FormsApplicationDelegate class

```
 public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

My main app works only after I have updated the Finishedlaunching Method. AppDelegate is inherited by UIApplicationDelegate class

```
   UIWindow window;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init();
        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        window.RootViewController = new Login().CreateViewController();
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
```

My question is when my other app is working fine with default code why my second application is not working and I have to add RootViewController.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Is both two projects Xamarin.forms project?

Comment: Yes, both project on Xamarin Forms and VS 2017.

Comment: Can you search your Main app if there is some code like  `LoadApplication(new App());` there? Forms should be init otherwise pages in the Xamarin.forms won't be load.

Comment: The second project looks like a Xamarin.iOS project.

Comment: No, it is default project created when you create xamarin forms Cross-platform App. Also, I have tried with default code in Project 2 but it was giving me the error . I have to remove the LoadApplication(new App()) because it was not working.

Comment: Can you share the second project here? I'm sure if you create a default Xamarin.forms project, the code in the `FinishedLaunching` should contain `LoadApplication(new App());`.

Comment: Are you sure you have created a Xamarin.Forms Project? And it's not a native iOS one?

Comment: Yes, pretty much I have created the Xamarin Forms Cross Project app.

Comment: Then this is actually not possible unless there is something wrong with your template

Comment: There is no need for you to remove the LoadApplication(new App()) and change the FormsApplicationDelegate. These codes won't cause the exception. If you can share enough code to reproduce the problem or share a sample project, we will check for you.

Comment: I'll share the IOS project in a while

Comment: Ok, will check once you share it.